# simple keypress doesn't fire any listener

Tags: extjs, listener

Simple new-to-sencha question that has me stumped for a while. I am trying to have an event fire on keypress. I want the event to be bound on the TextField. I have created a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CjyFt/1/

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.on('click', function() {
        console.log('Clicked'); // doesn't fire either
    });        
}
```

I have tried them each separately if that is a concern...

```
...        
enableKeyEvents: true,
listeners : {
    scope: this,
    'keypress' : function(textfield, e) {
        console.log('lovely'); // doesn't fire
    }
}
...
```

I have tried placing the listener in every parent class and I have tried to bind different events without any of them working, can someone take a look and see if it's something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [keypress](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-keypress) event (as well the related configuration option `enableKeyEvents`) is defined in `Ext.form.field.Text`, however you're extending your class `Ext.form.CustomField` from `Ext.form.field.Base`, which is the parent class of `Ext.form.field.Text` and therefore does not have this event (see [class hierarchy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text)).

I've updated your fiddle and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/CjyFt/2/

I just changed this:

```
Ext.define('Ext.form.CustomField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text', // instead of Ext.form.field.Base
...
```

The click event on the button already worked for me, so I don't think there is a problem with that.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, that makes sense now that I know why it's not working. In my defense, how was I supposed to know where the `enableKeyEvents` was defined? :(

Comment: You can see it in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-enableKeyEvents). At the right side of each property, function or event the class which defines it is displayed. Also, at [Ext.form.field.Base](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base) you won't find this config.